# Angular $routeparams empty using $stateprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am trying to have a link in my page such as:

```
 <a ng-href="#/Page/{{x.ID}}">{{x.ID}}</a>
```

Which succesfully gets to the angular controller but however the $routeparams are null when I am expecting to get the {{ x.ID }} back:

**pageController**.js

```
 angular.module("myApp.Pages").controller("pageController", ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);

}]);
```

And am referencing the state in my $stateprovider such as (in **appRouting.js**):

```
  $stateprovider.state('Page', {
        url: '/Page/:userId',
        templateUrl: 'App/Pages/page.html',
        controller: 'pageController'
    })
```

my **app.js**

```
 angular.module("myApp", [
  // User defined modules
  'myApp.Pages', // Pages
  'myApp.Core', // Core

  // Angular modules
  'ui.router', // state routing
  'ngRoute', // angular routing
  'LocalStorageModule', //local browser storage
  'angularRangeSlider',
  'ngFileUpload'
])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `$routeParams.userId` ?

Answer (score 1):

$stateParams instead of $routeParams

Comment: I'm confused, why would you need 2 routers in the first place.